# Searching an array, scanning for a line and then deleting it with the 3 lines after it

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to search an array, scanning for a line, and then if found, delete it as well as the 3 lines after it.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); // creating array

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("countries.txt"));
        Scanner scanText = new Scanner (System.in); // opening a scanner for the file and the users input

        String result = "";

        while (scan.hasNext()){
            names.add(scan.nextLine());
        } // while it has the next line, add it to the array

        do {
            System.out.println("Type add to add, del to delete and stop to print the names.");
            result = scanText.next(); // gets a value for result variable

            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                System.out.println("Add a country: ");
                names.add(scanText.next());
                System.out.println("Please add three facts: ");
                for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                names.add(scanText.next());
                }
            }// if answer is add, ask what name and then add it to the array

            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("del")) {
                System.out.println("What country do you want to delete? ");
                names.remove(scanText.next());
```

This would get rid of the country I'm searching for but after it's deleted it, I can't figure out how I can delete the following 3 lines in the array.

Just for context, every country has 3 facts to follow it.

Comment: Please, tag your question. I think, this is Java, isn't it?

Comment: What are `names` and `scanText`?

Comment: Please provide some more code and details, you have not provided enough for us to really diagnose the problem

Comment: On the face of it, you could simply repeat the names.remove(scanText.next()); line as many times as it takes. But as the other comments say - more details needed to make sure.

Comment: Why do you store the "facts" in the `names` list, too? You should create a model class, which holds the country name and a collection of facts. Your `names` collection can then be something like this: `List<CountryFacts> names = ....` (you should think about using a different name than `"name"` in that case).

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = names.index(scanText.next()):
if(index > -1 && index + 3 < names.size()) {
    for(int i = index; i < index + 3; i++) {
       names.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're removing values from list, you should make it from the end to start like this:

```
for(int i = names.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   names.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: This deletes the entire array apart from the first entry "0", what I need it to do is find an element within a list of 25, skip 3 entries forward then delete 4 backwards?

Comment: I just told you how you need to make it, now you can add your limitations to the `for` loop